# How can I access the "count" from the response in SPLObjectStorage?

Tags: php, guzzle

I am getting this:

[image]

How do I receive the count. I've tried a couple of ways like $r->count and $r->count();

This is a gist.

```
// Results is an SplObjectStorage object where each request is a key
    foreach ($results as $request) {
        // Get the result (either a ResponseInterface or RequestException)
        $result = $results[$request];
        if ($result instanceof ResponseInterface) {
            // Interact with the response directly
            $r = $result->getBody();
            echo $r;

        } else {
            // Get the exception message
            echo $result->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is there a down-vote? I fail to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that's a JSON string, You could decode it into an object using **[json_decode](http://www.php.net/json_decode)**

```
 $r = $result->getBody();
 $response=json_decode($r);
 echo $response->count;
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/1HxmLD5l)**

Comment: Nope, getting this error: Undefined property: stdClass::$count

Comment: Then probably the string you have is not exactly that. See the fiddle in updated answer

Comment: Strange, I am getting the exact same body, but that error is there.

Comment: What does your `echo $r;` exactly print in text?

Comment: `var_dump($r)`; will also help spot any extra characters

Comment: Can you add that as text so I can copy it as it is?

Comment: Sure, here: 
{"count":146,"url":"http:\/\/stylehatch.co\/"}{"id":"http:\/\/www.google.com","shares":17,"comments":897}

Comment: That is not a valid JSON string then, it has multiple root elements. This answer then wont work as it is, would have to change the string

Comment: This is but not complete one you pasted. `{"count":146,"url":"http:\/\/stylehatch.co\/"}{"id":"http:\/\/www.google.com","s‌​hares":17,"comments":897}` is not valid. see http://www.jsonlint.org

Comment: No leave that, I combined it unnecessarily. Right now, how do I get that count for the first one. The one I pasted above. The JSON is valid:(

Comment: See this fiddle for your string. It shows 146 to me correctly. And its a new fiddle: http://codepad.org/llpTOCaL

Comment: Yes you are right. It is very strange. I am using Guzzle on Laravel 4. Says undefined property on STDCass $count  here echo $response->count;

Comment: Maybe you should do  `var_dump(json_decode($r));` to find out what you get in that object

Comment: Also, I tried to echo $response, got this "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" Var Dump: 
object(stdClass)#291 (2) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(146)
  ["url"]=>
  string(21) "http://stylehatch.co/"
}
object(stdClass)#290 (3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(21) "http://www.google.com"
  ["shares"]=>
  int(9341603)
  ["comments"]=>
  int(897)
}

Comment: Then the answer still is correct :) Notice your first JSON string has a field named `count` and that is shown but your second string does not have `count` and that is why you get that error notice.

Comment: It doesn't even work for my first string, let alone the second. I dont think the answer is correct given that it's an Stdclass object, so I might need it to convert it to an array etc. Check my answer ;) thanks for your help though

Comment: If it doesn't work for your case, for which there could be many reasons, it doesn't mean its incorrect; You've seen the fiddle as well. And if you really needed it in an array format you can simply provide a second parameter to json_decode to return as an array. However I've got no more time to spend on this. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I had to use `get_object_vars()`. Converts an object to array.

```
 $r = $result->getBody();
 $response=json_decode($r);
 $s = get_object_vars($response);
 dd($s->count);
```